# How navigation menu responsive on mobile tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make my navigation menu keep responsive on mobile and tablet, but it always break into new line when I tested responsive mobile from browser development tool.

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Application Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>

      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="New"><i class='fa fa-floppy-o'></i>&nbsp;New</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Edit"><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Authorize"><i class='fa fa-check'></i>&nbsp;Cancel</a></li>

    <li>
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID" ID="ID">

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="btn-group" style="padding: 9px 0px 0px 0px; margin-left: 15px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More Action</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">
                         <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                     </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="copy('frm')"><i class='fa fa-files-o'></i>&nbsp;Copy Record</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="paste('frm')"><i class='fa fa-clipboard'></i>&nbsp;Paste Record</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Reverse"><i class='fa fa-reply'></i>&nbsp;Reverse Record</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="listLive"><i class='fa fa-list'></i>&nbsp;List Live Record</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="listAuth"><i class='fa fa-list'></i>&nbsp;List Un-authorize Record</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="listHist"><i class='fa fa-list'></i>&nbsp;List History Record</a></li>

          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="exportCSV.apply(this,['frm','export.csv'])"><i class='fa fa-print'></i>&nbsp;Export Record</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[image]

I would like to keep menu button, input box and dropdown menu keep as one line even on the mobile tablet break point.

How can I archive that, I'm not sure if problem caused from this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` but the only goal I would like to keep it as responsive. Thanks.

Comment: add ``.nav>li {
    display: inline-block;
}`` and lets work form there. Or add an image of the expected result.

Comment: add that on your desire breakpoint

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, thanks very much, please refer to edited question, navigation break into two line as the screen open as mobile, How can I keep it as one line even on mobile or tablet device? Thanks.

Comment: What will be our breakpoint?

Comment: @Houy Narun -- Post the CSS too.

Comment: @TomMichew, from above html code, I did not have additional css beside bootstrap class.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO, break point is on mobile, but I want to keep it as it is at tablet device. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the browser zoomed? I'm unable to recreate the issue shown in your image https://codeply.com/go/XaLXpSQyA0

Comment: @TomMichew, if you use built-in browser responsive utility, choosing width and height of tablet, then you will see problem as in picture.

Comment: @TomMichew I used pixel admin template http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07403R9 and apply menu as above to it. When I test responsiveness from browser responsive tool, the navigation menu always change in resize as in picture above when I clicked on toggle sidebar button at the left top of pixel admin template. That's my problem, and I want to keep it stay on one line on desktop and tablet screen device. Sorry that I could not post the whole template here, but only part of my problem. Thanks.